# How can i load my cordova project inside react native webview?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, cordova, mobile

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { View, ScrollView, Text, Modal, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class Chat extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
            
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, height:500}}>
            <Text>Header Menu</Text>
            <WebView source={{ uri : 'https://uatlinktowebapp.com/'}} style={{ flex:1 }} scalesPageToFit/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Currently i am just loading the web app which is just a replica of the cordova mobile app. The app that i want to include is having cordova plugins so can i include that in react native mobile app.